# jQuery not recognising input element

Tags: jquery, html

I was trying to imitate a Lynda.com example on appending elements using jQuery. This involved appending an additional  element but I couldn't get it working. I ended up just breaking things down to its bare minimum and I still can't get it working.

```
<h1>Here are my paragraphs</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
<form>
    <input value="(enter text here)"></input>
</form>
```

The jQuery code I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';
var $group = $("input");
$group.append("<br><p>TEST TEST TEST</p>"); 
});
```

Obviously, as I'm here, this doesn't work - even though it's pretty much exactly as written in the lesson. Interestingly, if I replace "input" with "p",  "h1" or even "form" then the "TEST TEST TEST" appends to those elements as expected.

I tried to search online for similar issues but have been unsuccessful. If someone could explain what I'm not understanding here I would be very, very grateful.

Comment: i think you got mistake with input tag, input always close with `/` like `<input type="text" value="(enter text here)" />`

Comment: Also, you cannot append to an input.

Comment: you only not recognise how append elements in jquery

Comment: Aw man, I had a massive derp moment where I just realised the example was appending to the <div> element which held the <input>. When you said straight out 'can't be done' this made me look back more thoroughly at the original examples HTML. Thanks so much for clearing that up and sorry for wasting time on a very simple answer - at the very least I've now learned a limitation of append(). Chur!

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because, input can't contain any other html tags. Wrap the input with a `div` and append your elements inside that `div`.
Code example:

```
<h1>Here are my paragraphs</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
<form>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <input value="(enter text here)">
  </div>
</form>
```

Then the jquery:

```
var $group = $(".wrapper");
$group.append("<br><p>TEST TEST TEST</p>");
```

Comment: Ha ha, yeah I just realised this now when it became known that <input> cannot be appended. Thanks, I appreciate the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your jquery code still works fine. inspect the input element in chrome debugger you can see that TEST TEST TEST is appended between the input tages that you have in your html. [chrome debugger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyvec.png)

The reason it is not rendered up in the page because we  cannot have these elements within input tag

Comment: Ah, cool. That explains why I cannot do it to <input> specifically. Thanks for elaborating - it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a div around the input inside the form like this:

```js
$(function() {

 'use strict';
  var $group = $(".group");
  $group.append("<br><p>TEST TEST TEST</p>"); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Here are my paragraphs</h1>
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p>This is the second paragraph</p>
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input value="(enter text here)">
  </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just found that out now, feel quite the fool for what seems kind of obvious now. Appreciate the response, thanks!

Comment: @thatsHeavyDoc - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: :D Don't worry, you'll soon build your reputation. No problem!